# How to fix error 1054 after creating an after update trigger

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a problem updating data after creating a trigger. The trigger joins 2 tables (people and churches) and should update the churchID on an update of a church name in the churches table.

I've tried to put the subquery in the set statement but I got a different **error 1093** saying you can't specify the target table 'people' in the `FROM` clause.

Here's my trigger

```sql
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER churchID_update_change AFTER UPDATE ON people
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF NEW.church != OLD.church THEN
    UPDATE people as p, (SELECT DISTINCT c.churchID
FROM churches c LEFT OUTER JOIN people p
    ON c.name = p.church
    WHERE NEW.church = c.name) as new_church
    SET p.churchID = new_church
    WHERE NEW.church = NEW.church;
    END IF;
END
$$
delimiter ;
```

Here's the update I'm trying to do:

```sql
UPDATE people
SET church = 'Efree'
WHERE firstname = 'Mark';
```

The people table has the following fields:

- PersonID int NOT NULL PK
- firstname varchar NOT NULL
- lastname varchar NOT NULL
- phone varchar
- List item
- church varchar NOT NULL
- churchID int NOT NULL fk (refrences churchID in churches table)
- address varchar
- email varchar
- notes varchar

the churches database is

- churchID INT NOT NULL pk
- name varchar NOT NULL pk
- phone VARCHAR
- address VARCHAR
- notes VARCHAR

What I'm trying to do with this trigger is whenever a persons church is changed it automatically changes the churchID to the churchID that lines up in the churches table

For example if you do

```
SELECT churchID
FROM churches
WHERE name = 'federated';
```

it would return the churchID of 1, or if you did

```
`SELECT churchID`
FROM churches
WHERE name = 'EFree'
```

it would return the churchID of 6

So after the update I'm doing now it should return the 'firstname' of Mark and 'churchID' of 6.

The exact error is `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'new_church' in 'field list'`

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  I don't understand the update you want to do . . . are `'Mark'` and `'Efree'` somehow passed as constants into the trigger.

Comment: `new_church` is an alias for a derived table - not a column name. So you can't use `SET p.churchID = new_church`

Comment: @GordonLinoff did my edits help it make more sense? I added what it is at right now and what exactly I'm trying to get it to.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel so how would you suggest going about it then?

Comment: @Unbarred I don't know, what you are trying to do. Add sample data for both tables (a couple of rows), your UPDATE statement and the expected result (changed sample data) after the UPDATE statement.

Comment: @Unbarred . . . No.  Why are you using a trigger for this?  Just use an `update` to change the values.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I'm making a trigger for this because I'm trying to have it be automated whenever it is changed.

Comment: @PaulSpiegel Alright, I added what the tables have, then some sample selects and exactly what I'm trying to get to. I think that should help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out after a lot of google searching. I found out that I didn't need the `UPDATE` clause and in order to use my subquery in the `SET` clause I needed to nest the subquery in another one. Here's my fixed code:

```
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER churchID_people_updateTrig BEFORE UPDATE on people
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
IF NEW.church != OLD.church THEN
SET new.churchID =  (SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT c.churchID 
FROM churches c LEFT OUTER JOIN people p 
    ON c.name = p.church
WHERE p.church = NEW.church) as x);
END IF;
END
$$
delimiter ;
```